# State of affairs of WebAssembly MVP in browsers

Tags: webassembly

https://webassembly.github.io/demo/ says: "Full execution semantics implemented." sounds like MVP is done, but what exactly is missing or am I doing anything wrong?

WAST:

```
(module
    (memory 1)

    (export "growMemory" $growMemory)
    (func $growMemory (param $0 i32) (result i32) (grow_memory (get_local $0)))

    (export "getMemorySize" $getMemorySize)
    (func $getMemorySize (result i32) (memory_size))
)
```

JS-Code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'build/test.wasm', true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.onload = function() {
    var module = Wasm.instantiateModule(new Uint8Array(xhr.response));
    console.log(module.exports.getMemorySize());
    console.log(module.exports.growMemory(1));
    console.log(module.exports.getMemorySize());
};
xhr.send(null);
```

Chrome Canary loads the WASM file but grow_memory seems to be unimplemented:

```
65536
0
65536
```

And Firefox Nightly fails at loading:

```
TypeError: wasm validation error at offset 124: bad expression code
```

Also the page size seems to be 0x10000 instead of 0x1000. But I can't find it in the design or spec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**March 2017 update:**

WebAssembly MVP has [reached consensus](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webassembly/2017Feb/0002.html):

> WebAssembly CG members representing four browsers, Chrome, Edge, Firefox,
>   and WebKit, have reached consensus that the design of the initial ([MVP](http://webassembly.org/docs/mvp/))
>   WebAssembly API and binary format is complete to the extent that no further
>   design work is possible without implementation experience and significant
>   usage. This marks the end of the Browser Preview and signals that browsers
>   can begin shipping WebAssembly on-by-default. From this point forward,
>   future features will be designed to ensure backwards compatibility.
>
> This consensus includes a [JavaScript API](http://webassembly.org/docs/js/) and [binary format](http://webassembly.org/docs/binary-encoding/)
>   accompanied by a [reference interpreter](https://github.com/WebAssembly/spec/tree/master/interpreter). You can test out WebAssembly
>   today using the Emscripten toolchain by following the [developer’s guide](http://webassembly.org/getting-started/developers-guide/)
>   and reading more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly).
>
> The next steps will be to form a W3C Working Group, to produce a
>   specification for the initial version of WebAssembly, and to continue
>   iterating on [future features](http://webassembly.org/docs/future-features/) in the current Community Group. To get
>   involved, you can join [design discussions](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/issues/) and [contribute](http://webassembly.org/community/contributing/) to the the
>   WebAssembly GitHub project.

The current [webassembly.org](http://webassembly.org) site documents the following next steps to follow right after MVP:

> The WebAssembly community group and contributors plan to:
>
> - distill the [design](https://github.com/webassembly/design)
>     and [spec interpreter](https://github.com/WebAssembly/spec/tree/master/interpreter) repos
>     into a single unified specification in the [spec](https://github.com/WebAssembly/spec)
>     repo
> - propose a new charter for a W3C WebAssembly Working Group
> - graduate the [WebAssembly LLVM backend](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/tree/master/test/CodeGen/WebAssembly) from experimental to stable (and update Emscripten)
> - prototype additional WebAssembly integration into browser developer tools
> - Start work on [post-MVP features](/docs/future-features/)

---

**November 2016 update:**

There's currently a browser preview, soliciting developer feedback. From [webassembly.org](http://webassembly.org/roadmap/):

> The [WebAssembly Community Group](https://w3.org/community/webassembly/) has an initial ([MVP](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/MVP.md)) binary format release candidate and JavaScript API which are implemented in several browsers. The CG is now soliciting feedback from the broader community as part of a Browser Preview period. The tentative goal of the CG is for the Browser Preview to conclude in Q1 2017, though significant findings during the Browser Preview could potentially extend the duration. When the Browser Preview concludes, the CG will produce a draft specification of WebAssembly and browser vendors can start to ship conforming implementations on-by-default.
>
> Developers should be aware that between the Browser Preview and public launch of WebAssembly, there will be at least one breaking change which will require developers to update their toolchain and binaries. These changes will be announced ahead of time and are listed below.
>
> See [Getting Started](http://webassembly.org/getting-started/developers-guide/) to start experimenting and [Feedback](http://webassembly.org/community/feedback/) for how and where to direct feedback.

---

**Original answer:**

We synchronized on feature parity between browsers for the demos and intend to update all browsers + demos in lockstep from now on, towards MVP.

We have something that currently works, but it's not stable. As we work with larger and more diverse codebase we're hoping to kick the tires, see what could be improved, and gain confidence that post-MVP features will be implementable without headache. We also want feedback from developers to make sure what we've build is usable!

It's missing some features such as the API to the `Wasm` JavaScript object, memory and pointer sharing across `Wasm` instances. We're also not settled on the binary format, the biggest change for now is going post-order but there are plenty of smaller changes coming.

Browser integration is also lacking: we want to ship with view-source and likely some debugging support. There's also some perf tuning, and plenty of security testing.

To track those issues I recommend looking at the [design](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/issues) and [spec](https://github.com/WebAssembly/spec/issues) issue trackers.

On your specific problem, we haven't finished `grow_memory` in Chrome. Work has started though.

Comment: Thanks for the swift answer, I found the page size issue: https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/pull/442